# Sonar Runner + Jenkins not working with SVN

Tags: svn, jenkins, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I have successfully integrated Sonar Runner with Jenkins having Sonar Qube already running as a service.

When I configure sonar-project.properties file to analyse the source code (JAVA) from a location on my computer, it works correctly and I am able to see the results of the run.

But when I tried doing the same by taking a SVN checkout as configured in Jenkins, following error is shown on the Jenkins console :

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "svn"
```

This error is thrown once checkout has been successful and analysis has already been done. Not sure, what leads to this error.

Do anyone here ever encountered this kind of error with Sonar and Jenkins?

Version of Sonar Runner - 5.1
Version of SonarQube - 2.4

Comment: What is the version of the SonarQube SVN Plugin on your instance?

Answer (score 0):

Please update to version 1.1 of SonarQube SVN Plugin that is no more relying on external `svn` command but is instead using pure Java implementation (SVNKit).

Comment: Thanks Julien, but I already tried this and still getting the same issue.

Comment: Then show the full stack trace. The SQ SVN Plugin 1.1 is not using external svn command. Have you also installed the SCMStat plugin?